# AS3: Setting size of loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, width, loader

I'm using Loader to load an external swf into my swf and adding that loaded swf to the stage using event.target.content.

If i set the width and height of the loaded swf I actually resize the movieclip inside my loaded swf. What I wanna do is change the stage size of the loaded swf.

Any way of doing that?

Comment: I haven't ever encountered a case where you'd want or need to do that. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a swf that loads whatever other swf for generating a thumbnail of the loaded swf. My swf has a set width and height where the loaded swf should fit perfectly. The problem is that i can't set the width and height of the loaded swf, so it extends outside where it's supposed to be..

I found out that you could use scaleX and scaleY, but I'm not sure how to find the same scale as the place I wanna load it into (witch is 900 x 506 btw)

Comment: Actually.. The swf that I was testing with just consisted of a single small rectangle. When I added something to my test swf that was extending the document class size, width worked as it should.

Still wierd that I only can change the size of the content and not the stage of the loaded swf..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find the scale you need is to compare the ratios of the width and height scales of the content and the target. 
To make the loaded swf fit within the area, scaling so that everything is inside you can do something like this:

```
var scale:Number = Math.min( _holder.width / _loader.content.width,
                            _holder.height / _loader.content.height );
_loader.content.scaleX = _loader.content.scaleY = scale;
```

This will make sure that you can see everything. If you change Math.min to Math.max, you will get a different result if the dimensions don't match